# Programatically sort pages in a Visio Document using VBA

Tags: vba, visio

Does anyone know a method to sort Visio pages alphabetically using VBA?

I looked to see if a method such as `vzdVisioDocument.Pages.Sort` exists, but found nothing in documentation or through internet searches.

Do I need to write my own sorting function using the `Application.ActiveDocument.Pages.ItemU("Page Name").Index` property? That seems to be the method suggested by recording a macro of the action.

Comment: This seems like a fun task, i'm gonna give it a go

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 [nerd-sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/)? ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Wow that's a good approach, maybe i'll-- *FWOOOM*

Comment: On second thought... "I will have no part in this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned this in another comment, but when I made some test pages, it was always shuffling the pages around when I ran it because I the way that this is implemented, I don't believe that `Exit For` should be in there.

I also swapped the comparison to `StrCompare` due to personal preference along with the order of the for loops.

```
Sub PageSort()

    Dim titlesColl As Collection
    Set titlesColl = New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Pages.Count
        titlesColl.Add ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(i).Name
    Next i

    Dim title As Variant
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Pages.Count
        For Each title In titlesColl
            If StrComp(ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(i).Name, title, vbTextCompare) < 0 Then
                ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(title).index = i
            End If
        Next title
    Next i

    Set titlesColl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I agree with you that `StrComp` is the better method for comparing the titles. I think the reason the shuffling was happening is because the title to compare and the title to compare against are switched in your `StrComp` statement. This would cause each title to be assigned multiple indices on a single pass (which breaks with `Exit For`). If you switch the order, the `Exit For` saves you computational expense.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I think it has to do with Some pages being background pages. Read that BG pages are not sortable. So I confirmed this by making a copy of file and deleting all the BG pages, and it worked, however it is not alphabetizing them correctly. So can you please give code to skip BG pages and see why it is not putting the pages alphabetically?

Answer (score 2):

So that wasn't as painful as expected. With `vzdVisioDocument` as an already defined `Visio.Document`:

```
' Make a collection of titles to iterate through
Dim colPageTitles As Collection
Set colPageTitles = New Collection

Dim intPageCounter As Integer
For intPageCounter = 1 To vzdVisioDocument.Pages.Count
    colPageTitles.Add vzdVisioDocument.Pages.Item(intPageCounter).Name
Next intPageCounter

' For each title in the collection, iterate through pages and find the appropriate new index
Dim intPageIndex As Integer
Dim varPageTitle As Variant
For Each varPageTitle In colPageTitles
    For intPageIndex = 1 To vzdVisioDocument.Pages.Count
        ' Check to see if the title comes before the index's current page title
        If StrComp(varPageTitle, vzdVisioDocument.Pages.Item(intPageIndex).Name) < 0 Then
            ' If so, set the new page index
            vzdVisioDocument.Pages.ItemU(varPageTitle).Index = intPageIndex
            Exit For
        End If
    Next intPageIndex
Next varPageTitle

' Clean up
Set colPageTitles = Nothing
```

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - This works, but I'm looking forward to seeing what you've got - sure it will be more elegant.

Comment: Good stuff, this is fundamentally the same approach I took lol

Comment: Good old insertion sort

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if it's just my machine or not, but when I made pages to test this it would just shuffle them all around every time I ran it. That was fixed by removing the `Exit For` from the inside loop. Additionally, the results were in reverse alphabetical order for me so changing the operator to `>` worked for me

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - Updated my answer with your recommendation for using `StrComp`.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - I just ran through both solutions again. I think the disconnect is that I'm using `vbBinaryCompare` (default) vice text compare. The pages in my application are programmatically named "A.1", "A.2.1", etc - so I buy some cycles doing it this way. I'm accepting your answer as the one that is probably best for a wide audience.  Thanks for helping me proof this.

Comment: Oh that's totally the disconnect - the example names I was working with were all text so this was confusing the hell out of me how it was working for you

Comment: I was writing up a big 'answer' full of test cases step by step that didn't work for me

Comment: I also learned an interesting thing while doing this: If you programmatically set a page's name using `Document.Pages(item).Name = "Some name"` it sets that new name in both the `.Item()` and `.ItemU()` indexes.  If you then manually change the name in Visio, it only changes the `.Item()` index.  Trying to reference it using `.ItemU()` will throw an object error.

Comment: That... doesn't sound like intended behavior. Also, I don't think I see the reason that a read-only collection of those items had to be created

Comment: Probably comes with adapting a stand-alone product to fit the VBA object scheme.  Obscure edge cases are... obscure.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub reorderPages()

```
Dim PageNameU() As String

Dim isBackgroundPage As Boolean
Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
Dim vsoCellObj As Visio.Cell

'// Get All Pages
Dim i As Integer
For Each vsoPage In ActiveDocument.Pages

    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve PageNameU(i)
    PageNameU(i) = vsoPage.NameU

Next vsoPage

For i = 1 To UBound(PageNameU)

    Set vsoPage = vsoPages.ItemU(PageNameU(i))
    Set vsoCellObj = vsoPage.PageSheet.Cells("UIVisibility")

    isBackgroundPage = vsoPage.Background

    '// Make foreground page to set page index
    If isBackgroundPage = True Then
        vsoCellObj.FormulaU = visUIVNormal
        vsoPage.Background = False
    End If

    vsoPage.Index = NumNonAppSysPages + i

    '// Set to background page
    If isBackgroundPage = True Then
        vsoCellObj.FormulaU = visUIVHidden
        vsoPage.Background = True
    End If

Next i
```

End Sub